# TextWriter.WriteLine IO Exception - The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: c#, console-application, windows-server-2003, ioexception, streamwriter

I am trying to write text file after reading from a large tab delimited text file in a console application. Issue is that if I run many instances of this exe concurrently on a server, it gives me runtime error at TextWriter.WriteLine and then application crashes because of unhandled exception. This happens with all the instances. I fail to understand the reason for this behavior.. Is it because I am not using StringBuilder which will use memory dynamically ?

My code is as follows :

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@FilePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
 string mainLine = sr.ReadLine();
 string[] fileHeaders = mainLine.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
 string newLine = "";

 System.IO.StreamWriter outFileSw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@outFile);

 while (!sr.EndOfStream)
 {
    mainLine = sr.ReadLine();
    string[] originalLine = mainLine.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

   newLine = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaders.Length; i++)
   {
      if(fileHeaders[i].Trim() != "")
       newLine = newLine + fileHeaders[i].Trim() + "=" + originalLine[i].Trim() + "&";
   }

outFileSw.WriteLine(newLine.Remove(newLine.Length - 1));
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@outFile);

  if (fileInfo.Length > (1.3 * 1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0)) // greater than 1.3 GB  
  {
          outFileSw.Close();
          outFileNumber = outFileNumber + 1;
          outFileSw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@outFile + outFileNumber.ToString() + ".txt");
  }

}
outFileSw.Dispose();
sr.Close();
sr.Dispose();
```

Error details are :

```
Exception Message: The specified network name is no longer available.

Stack Trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
 at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
 at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
 at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
 at ExampleExe.ExampleProcess.FnFiles()


 Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available.

 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
 at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(Boolean calledFromFinalizer)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Finalize()
```

Thanks,
Kanu

Comment: Do you ever close those files? `using(){}` is very useful in these cases.

Comment: @nrodic: Yes.. I do close and dispose after processing the complete file from which I am reading. Further, the error happens when the application is trying to write the file.

Comment: @nordic: I edited the question text to show how I do Close and Dispose...

Comment: Do you write concurrently from many processes into the same file?

Comment: @nrodic: Nope.. Thing is that I run max 8 instances concurrently. All of them reading and writing different files but only from and to same folders.. and this error is also not encountered everytime. It occurs randomly. This is why it made me think that it is probably dynamic memory issue...

Comment: Are you writing on a network path? Ideally you would want to buffer instead of writing each line, that would reduce number of raw IO. You can buffer e.g. 10MB into stringbuider or byte buffer before dumping the content to file.

Comment: There is a MS KB article on this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961293 which mentions this can be caused by Symantec Endpoint Protection.

Comment: @loopedcode: I am reading and writing files on same network path. However, the console application is set up on another server. I was thinking that there is problem with the server where I have the exe running .... as this problem seem to happen when this server has many other processes running.

Comment: @loopedcode: I saw this article.. We don't have Symantec..

Comment: Don't `Close()` *and* `Dispose()`. Choose one or the other. Further, use `using` as per nrodic and it'll take care of the `Dispose()` for you and you'll not need to worry about either.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer: Will do that..

Comment: The error message means that the connection to the server got broken. That is where you need to focus your investigation.

Comment: @RaymondChen : Came across [link](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/239423-the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available-while-writing-to-shared-dir) .. Application server looks ok and its AVG's Resident Shield is disabled too .. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Try taking a network trace and a filemon trace.

Comment: @loopedcode : I think what you say about raw IO might be true ... I wanted to try writing to buffer before writing to a file. Could you point to a code which will help me understand how should I go about doing it ?

Comment: @kanu: I posted a sample below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a FileWriter with StringBuilder buffer. It uses a separate thread to write while main thread keeps accumulating data. Writes 10MB buffer at a time. Buffered data is kept in Queue object; writer thread removes item from this Queue and writes it out full using with File.AppendAllText method.

```
private Queue<StringBuilder> writeQueue;
private bool isComplete;

public void FileWriter()
{
    this.isComplete = false;
    this.writeQueue = new Queue<StringBuilder>();

    var writer = new Action<string>(this.StartWriting);
    var writerAsync = writer.BeginInvoke(@"outputfile.txt", null, null);

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"inputfile.txt"))
    {
        var fileHeaders = sr.ReadLine()
            .Split('\t')
            .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
            .Select(j => j.Trim())
            .ToList();

        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var originalLine = sr.ReadLine()
                .Split('\t')
                .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
                .Select(j => j.Trim())
                .ToList();

            var line = new StringBuilder();
            //Must have same number of items
            if (originalLine.Count == fileHeaders.Count)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaders.Count(); i++)
                {
                    line.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", fileHeaders[i], originalLine[i]);
                }
                line.AppendLine();
            }

            buffer.AppendLine(line.ToString());
            if (buffer.Length > 1024 * 1024 * 10)//approx 10MB 
            {
                lock (this.writeQueue)
                {
                    this.writeQueue.Enqueue(buffer);
                }
                buffer = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        //Queue any final remaining data
        if (buffer.Length>0) lock (this.writeQueue)
        {
            this.writeQueue.Enqueue(buffer);
        }
    }
    this.isComplete = true;
    writer.EndInvoke(writerAsync);
}

private void StartWriting(string outFilePath)
{
    while (!this.isComplete || this.writeQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder queuedItem;
        if (this.writeQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (this.writeQueue)
            {
                queuedItem = this.writeQueue.Dequeue();
            }
            File.AppendAllText(outFilePath, queuedItem.ToString());
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //Sleep 5sec
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question ... even though I use buffer, there still will be limitation to the number of threads I run concurrently depending on a server ?

Comment: Number of threads would be limited by CPU time and resources. You will have to test whats optimal with different numbers to see whats optimal. Try with 2 and move up until you don't see any more performance gain. But ultimately you will be bottle-necked by network traffic for your remote file write to complete. And also, if you would be using this, then accept this as answer and vote up.